# GET API call failing in http Dart but working in Postman

Tags: flutter, api, dart, postman

I am trying to make a basic GET request in flutter using http package. Although I tried it multiple times while debugging it does not work, meanwhile making the same http request in Postman DOES work. What could be the reason?

This is the method I am using. Debugger stops working before entering the "try" statement.

```
  getCoordinatesFromPlaceId(String placeId) async {
    var client = http.Client();

    var url_coord =
        'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?fields=geometry&place_id=$placeId&key=APIKEY';
    var response = await client.get(
      Uri.parse(url_coord),
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
    );

    try {
      var jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
      
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

You can see the result in POstman:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static Future<dynamic?> getApiData() async {
    String url='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?fields=geometry&place_id=$placeId&key=APIKEY';
    try {
      var response = await http.get(
        Uri.parse(url),
        headers: <String, String>{
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        },
      );
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks, now it works. SHould I always use Futures to make API calls? Is it not enough to await for the response in an async function?

Comment: I always use Future to make API calls

Answer (score 1):

Postman can generate dart code request, have you tried it this way ?
https://blog.postman.com/use-your-work-in-postman-to-generate-code-for-your-apps/

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'll keep it in mind for the next time

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
 var url_coord =
        'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?fields=geometry&place_id=$placeId&key=APIKEY';
    var response1 = await get(
      Uri.parse(url_coord),
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
    );

    try {
      var jsonResponse = json.decode(response1.body);
      
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
```

EDIT

or

```
var url_coord =
        'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json';
    var response1 = await get(
      Uri.parse(url_coord).replace(queryParameters: {
        "fields":"geometry",
        "place_id" : $placeId ,
         "key" : "APIKEY"
      }),
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    );

    try {
      var jsonResponse = json.decode(response1.body);
      
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
```

Comment: HI, I get the same result as before.

Comment: You can check edited. Please specifiy error as well.

Answer (score 0):

try it with create specific model

1- put your json here [Json to Dart](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/),
it will generate a model for you.

then

2- use this model to fitch data
like a documentation [Fetch data from the internet](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data)

Answer (score 0):

**response type Response is by default available in dart library**

```
static Future<dynamic?> getApiData() async {
String url='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?fields=geometry&place_id=$placeId&key=APIKEY';
try {
  Response response = await http.get(
    Uri.parse(url),
    headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    },
  );
  if (response.isNotEmpty && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
  } else {
    return null;
  }
} catch (e) {
  return null;
}
```

}